# how to copy values of one array document to another document in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, set, hapi.js

I am trying to copy the data of one array document to another array document using mongoose with nodejs. the items of array document have reference/objectId to another collection. I am using `$set` in order retrieve this functionality like this:

```
var criteria = {
     mId: {
        $in: ["id1", "id2", "id3"]
     }
};
var options = {
    multi: true
}

var dataToSet = {
    $set : {
       destinationDocument : "$sourceDocument",
    }
}
table_name.update(criteria, dataToSet, options, function(err,result){
        if(err) {
           console.log(err)
        }
    });
```

But I am getting following error:

```
Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value "["$sourceDocument"]" at path "destinationDocument"
```

my db schema look like this

```
new Schema({
    idAutoIncrement: { type: Number,unique: true,index:true,sparse:true},
    destinationDocument: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Users",
    }],
    sourceDocument: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Users",
    }],
});
```

Can someone please help me figuring out what do I need to do in order to copy all the values of `sourceDocument` to `destinationDocument`. Any kind help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: which version of mongodb are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrayOfDocuments = [documentId1, documentId2, documentId3];

arrayOfDocuments.foreach(function(documentId) {

    var criteria = {
        mId: documentId
    };

    // Get column2 from a document
    const documentColumnTwo = await table_name.findById(documentId).select('column2');

    // Set column1 to column2
    var dataToSet = {
        $set : {
            'column1' : documentColumnTwo,
        }
    }

    // Update the document
    await table_name.update(criteria, dataToSet, options, function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick response Raymond. But I am looking for something different. Lets consider it in terms of rows and columns. My matching criteria may have multiple rows (see the criteria now in the edited question) instead of single row and for each row I want to update the value of `column1` of that row with the value of `column2` of the same row. So I want mongoose equivalent of following sql statement: `UPDATE table_name SET column1 = column2 WHERE mid IN ('id1', 'id2', 'id3')`.
Note: In my case `column1` and `column2` are an array of items which are reference to a different collection.

Comment: Look at my updated answer. It loops through an array of ids and for each id, it finds the document and copies the value from column2 to column1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation pipeline with $out to update the same collection.

But be careful while using `$out`. According to official mongodb documentation :

> **Create New Collection**
>
> The `$out` operation creates a new collection in the current database if one does not already exist. The
>   collection is not visible until the aggregation completes. If the
>   aggregation fails, MongoDB does not create the collection.
>
> **Replace Existing Collection**
>
> If the collection specified by the `$out` operation already exists, then upon completion of the
>   aggregation, the `$out` stage atomically replaces the existing
>   collection with the new results collection. Specifically, the `$out`
>   operation:
>
> 1. Creates a temp collection.
> 2. Copies the indexes from the existing
>      collection to the temp collection.
> 3. Inserts the documents into the
>      temp collection.
> 4. Calls db.collection.renameCollection with
>      dropTarget: true to rename the temp collection to the destination
>      collection.
>
> The `$out` operation does not change any indexes that existed on the
>   previous collection. If the aggregation fails, the `$out` operation
>   makes no changes to the pre-existing collection.

Try this :

```
table_name.aggregate([{
    $match : {
        mId: {
            $in: ["id1", "id2", "id3"]
        }
    }
},{
    $project : {
        idAutoIncrement: "$idAutoIncrement",
        destinationDocument: "$sourceDocument",
        sourceDocument: "$sourceDocument"
    }
},{
    $out : "table_name"
}])
```

**Don't forget to $project stage which you need in the collection. And please double check the output value first, either with a different temporary_collection or just by removing the $out stage and checking the result of aggregation pipeline.**

For detailed information please read [Official $out MongoDB documentation.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/)